# If Mouseover Div Equals False - JQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
if($('#myDiv').hover() == false) {
  myFunction();
}
```

Not getting much in the way of errors in Chrome or Firebug consoles. I've had a look at some other posts, and there was an answer that used something like:

```
if($('#myDiv').is(':hover') == false) {
  myFunction();
}
```

However this also doesn't work.

Here's a jsfiddle if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/yuwPR/2/

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers, I wasn't able to get anything working. I'm thinking it might not be possible. Oh well, I'll try something else!

Thanks again

p.s. Most inventive answer marked as right and upvotes all round.

Comment: Execute a function when the mouse isn't over a div.

Comment: You mean when the mouse leaves from over the div? Or execute a function over and over while the mouse is not over the div?

Comment: The latter, execute the function whenever the mouse is `not` over the div. Don't execute when it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sample sets up a global js variable to store the hover state of the div. Then I use jquery hover to toggle that between true / false. Then, we just fire off a function every 10ms that checks the hover state. Currently I am just setting the window status telling you if you're hovered or not.

```
var _MOUSEOVER_IN_PROGRESS = false; //stores the hover state
function isover(){
    if(_MOUSEOVER_IN_PROGRESS){
        window.status = 'Still over!';
    } else {
        window.status = 'You are not hovering on me!';
    }
    setTimeout("isover()",10); //checking every 10ms! 
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    isover();
    $('#mydiv').hover(
        function(){ _MOUSEOVER_IN_PROGRESS = true; }, 
        function(){ _MOUSEOVER_IN_PROGRESS = false; }
    );
});
```

Edited my code! My mydiv hover catch was not wrapped in a document ready

Comment: Hi Jage, thanks for the code, it looked good but hung my browser :-/

Comment: right now the function happenes every 10ms, you should change it to something more infrequent. Like 1000, which is every 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your ultimate intent, you could wire up a hover on the `document` and check the current `target.id`

```
$(document).mouseover(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id == "myDiv") {
        $("body").css("background-color", "red"); //over the div so change the color
        return;
    }
    $("body").css("background-color", "green"); //no on the div
});
```

**code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/27fPA/).**

Answer (score 1):

The hover function takes 2 callback functions:

```
('#myDiv').hover(function () {
        // function to call when hovering 
    }, 
    function () { 
        myFunction(); 
    }
);
```

So, when hovering is "false", ie, on mouse out, the second function will be called.

If you're only interested in doing something when the hover stops, you can use the `mouseout()` function:

```
$('#myDiv').mouseout(function() {
        myFunction();
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works initially, but after the first mouseout it executes the function wherever the mouse is.

Comment: @logic-unit - have you tried `mouseleave()` instead of `mouseout()`?

Comment: I've just adapted your jsfidle example to use the `mouseout()` vesion of my example and it appears to work as expected: every time the mouse rolls out of the div, an alert pops up.

Answer (score 1):

Your first call could never work:

```
$('#myDiv').hover()
```

This actually says "trigger the `hover` event on the element".  It does not check to see if your user is currently hovering over the element.

Your second formulation should work:

```
$('#myDiv').is(':hover')
```

This checks to see if the element currently has the mouse hovering over it.  However, it doesn't seem to work on document load.  An example that works can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yuwPR/3/).  If you can clarify what you're trying to do, it might be possible to find some working code in this style.

Comment: Thanks, this ideally what I'm after however it throws this error in Chrome: `Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: hover`